# Is it possible to save a Contact Sheet made in Flie Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, photos, microsoft-paint, irfanview

I am wanting to make a Contact Sheet ("A single sheet that multiple photos are attached to a paper [in photography this started out as "a piece of photographic paper onto which several or all of the negatives on a roll of film have been contact printed."]).

File Explorer has an option to make a Contact Sheet but, I don't know of a way to save the Contact Sheet and ***not*** print it. The way to make ***and*** print a Contact Sheet in File Explorer:

Pictures to follow along with explanation of how to make Contact Sheet in File Explorer:

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUxZA.jpg)

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Tnh.jpg)

1. Select the images that you want to put into a contact Sheet
2. Right Click on the selected photos, or tap with 2 fingers on the touchpad
3. Click Print
4. From the options of the organization for the paper, scroll down to the bottom and select Contact Sheet
5. Click Print

If there's a way to make a Contact Sheet without downloading any software, I'd like to know it

Some Software that I already have (I did research these a bit but, nothing seemed to come up for how to make a Contact Sheet):

- IrfanView
- PicsArt
- Paint
- Standard Windows Photos app

Thanks in advance for any help.

This May be the wrong place to ask this type of question but, it had a relation to the File Explorer, and that seems like good reason to ask here. If there's another Forum I should ask this on, please let me know.

Comment: I've been away from Windows for awhile, but my goto app for contact sheets was Irfanview.  You can easily define the page (number of images, spacing, etc.).  When you create the sheet(s), you have options for whether to save as a file or print.  See http://www.kearc.com/southernstringband/Irfanview/irfanproof.html

Comment: Does Thumbnails come with IrfanView?

Comment: Yes.  It has a built-in thumbnail utility.

Comment: @fixer1234 Could you please Write that as an answer? Then I can up vote that. In your answer I, and probably any one else that comes across this question, would appreciate that link, that you posted in an earlier comment, and or anything that can better help explain how to get to that Thumbnail utility.

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually, since you said "I've been away from Windows for awhile", I could post an answer, and mention you in the answer. That really helps thanks! Please reply on what I should do, if anything to provide an answer to this question. Sorry if you've been getting notified from all my comments, I didn't mean to submit some of those.

Comment: It's been some years since I used it, and it sounds like you've figured out how to do what you need.  My recollection is that a separate icon for the thumbnail viewer can be optionally installed when you load Irfanview but that it's readily available from the menu so a separate icon isn't really needed.  You can use the thumbnail viewer to select images for the contact sheet.  If you've figured it out, you're more current with it than I am, so yeah, feel free to post an answer.  :-)